# Is this an ANCS bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, ancs

I am working at a project which is using iPhone's ANCS.

I've noticed a strange behaviour if my phone is also connected to another device that is using ANCS (example: Pebble).

My device receives garbage packets. I've tried to comment out the part in my code that requests details on the Control Point characteristic. After this, I still receive nonsense data on the Data Source characteristic. Basically, I receive part of what Pebble is asking for. This is an example of nonsense packet:

> Data source: Data: 65 05 0F 00 32 30 31 35 30 35 32 36 54 31 34 33 36
>   31 33

Here i can see that Pebble is asking for the date. 05 is the attribute "0F 00" is length and "32 30 31 35 30 35 32 36 54 31 34 33 36 31 33" is the date when the notification was received.

I don't ask for anything and I'm still receiving packets. Is this an ANCS bug?

Comment: According to this answer, this is expected: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37824128/797767