# Do ANCS support sending notifications to multiple BLE devices?

Tags: ios, ancs

Multiple devices are paired to the same iPhone but only one receive the ANCS notifications..

Answer (score 1):

Testing on an iPhone 6+ with iOS 9.3.2 I can confirm that ANCS sends notifications to all devices that have subscribes with it.

That being said, when requesting notification attributes through the Control Point, iOS doesn't care which device requested it, the Data Source sends attribute data to all subscribed devices.